# Неверное содержимое .json файла

Tags: c#, json.net

Есть массив объектов класса Vector который нужно сериализовать. Содержимое json файла:

**{"length":15,"lineColor":3,"x":0,"y":15}:1,"x":2,"y":5}**

Сам класс вектор

```
  public enum Colors { Red = 1, Blue, Green }

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Vector
{
    [DataMember]
    private int x;
    [DataMember]
    private int y;
    [DataMember]
    private Colors lineColor;
    [DataMember]
    public double length;

    public Vector() { }
    public Vector(int x, int y, Colors lineColor)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.lineColor = lineColor;
        length = Length;
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get { return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)); }
        set { length = value; }
    }

    public void AddLength(double a)
    {
        length = Length + a;
    }

    public void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Line color: {0}\nCoordinates: ({1};{2})\nLength: {3}\n", lineColor, x, y, length);
    }


}
```

Класс, содержащий методы для сериализаций

```
    public class Manipulation
{
    public Manipulation() { }

    DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Vector));
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    public void JSonSerialize(Vector obj)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("serialization.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            js.WriteObject(fs, obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" Json serialization completed");
    }

    public void BinarySerialize(Vector obj)
    {
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("sr.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            bf.Serialize(fs, obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Binary serialization completed");
    }
}
```

Сериализация в блоке main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector v1 = new Vector(2, 5, (Colors)1);
        Vector v2 = new Vector(-3, 4, (Colors)2);
        Vector v3 = new Vector(0, 15, (Colors)3);

        Manipulation mn = new Manipulation();
        Vector[] vectors = new Vector[3] { v1, v2, v3 };
        foreach(Vector obj in vectors)
        {
            mn.JSonSerialize(obj);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Подобная проблема возникает и при XMl, и при binary сериализации. Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.Position = fs.Length;
js.WriteObject(fs, obj);
```

Но хорошего JSON-a так все равно не получится, так как отдельные объекты надо разделять запятыми, а весь набор - заворачивать в квадратные скобки. Сериализуйте сразу весь массив.